# How do I extract common rows from a dataframe?

Tags: r, rows

I'm trying to extract the common rows from a data frame, which is something like this:

```
   *DEPTH SALINITY DEPTH SALINITY
18    87    39.06    94    39.06
19   173    39.05   141       NA
20   260    39.00   188    39.07
21   312    38.97   207    39.03
22     1    39.36     1    39.35
23    10    39.36    10    39.33
24    20    39.36    20    39.33
25    30    39.35    30    39.33*
```

I want to extract the rows with the same depth.  I cannot do something like `data.frame[22:25,]` because I have lots of rows.

Comment: So you want rows where `*DEPTH` and `DEPTH` are equal?

Answer (score 0):

Do something like: `df[df$DEPTH == df$X.DEPTH,]` (`*` is not valid in R column names)